# How to use Google Map with Awesomium?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, awesomium

How to call this code in C#?

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };
```

Awesomium v1.7.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebControl.ExecuteJavascript` method to call your JS method from C#.

```
yourWebControl.ExecuteJavascript("initialize()");
```

If you need some result returned from javascript, it may be obtained from `ExecuteJavascriptWithResult`.

Global javascript objects that will persist between all loaded pages can be created with `CreateGlobalJavascriptObject` method.

See [documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl.htm) describing Awesomium `WebControl` methods.

Comment: Ok, how to create object mapOptions? and use global var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

Comment: I see, JSvalue has not method SetProperty. How to add value?

Comment: JSValue is value, not object - so it has no properties. But JSValue can be implicitly converted to JSObject, which has properties and so on. so if your JS code returns object, you can use something like `JSObject obj = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("some_code");`

Comment: Can you example with my code in question?